# Perl - Using Variables from an Input File in the URL when a Variable has a Space (two words)

Tags: ajax, json, perl, web-scraping

What am I doing?  The script loads a string from a .txt (locations.txt), and separates it into 6 variables.  Each variable is separated by a comma.  Then I go to a website, whose address depends on these 6 values.

What is the problem?  If there is a space as a character in a variable as part of a string in locations.txt.  When there is a space, it does not get the correct url.

The input file is:

```
 locations.txt = Heinz,Weber,Sierra Leone,1915,M,White
```

Because Sierra Leone has a space, the url is:

```
  https://familysearch.org/search/collection/results#count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3AHeinz%20%2Bsurname%3AWeber%20%2Bbirth_place%3A%22Sierra%20Leone%22%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1914-1918~%20%2Bgender%3AM%20%2Brace%3AWhite&collection_id=2000219
```

But that does not get processed correctly in the code below.

I'm using the packages:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
 use HTML::TableExtract;
 use Data::Dumper;
 use LWP::UserAgent;
 use JSON;
 use CGI qw/escape/;
 use HTML::DOM;
```

This is the beginning of the code :

```
 open(my $l, 'locations26.txt') or die "Can't open locations: $!";
 open(my $o, '>', 'out2.txt') or die "Can't open output file: $!";

 while (my $line = <$l>) {
      chomp $line;
       my %args;
      @args{qw/givenname surname birth_place birth_year gender race/} = split /,/, $line;
     $args{birth_year} = ($args{birth_year} - 2) . '-' . ($args{birth_year} + 2); 
      my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(create => 1, activate => 1); 
      $mech->get("https://familysearch.org/search/collection/results#count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3A".$args{givenname}."%20%2Bsurname%3A".$args{surname}."%20%2Bbirth_place%3A".$args{birth_place}."%20%2Bbirth_year%3A".$args{birth_year}."~%20%2Bgender%3AM%20%2Brace%3AWhite&collection_id=2000219");  

# REST OF THE SCRIPT HERE. MANY LINES.
```

}

As another example, the following would work:

```
locations.txt = Benjamin,Schuvlein,Germany,1913,M,White
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Mechanize, so not sure whether you need to encode the URL. Try encoding space to `%20` or `+` before running `$mech->get`

```
$url =~ s/ /+/g;
```

Or

```
$url =~ s/ /%20/g
```

whichever works :)

====
**Edit:**

```
my $url = "https://familysearch.org/search/collection/results#count=20& query=%2Bgivenname%3A".$args{givenname}."%20%2Bsurname%3A".$args{surname}."%20%2Bbirth_place%3A".$args{birth_place}."%20%2Bbirth_year%3A".$args{birth_year}."~%20%2Bgender%3AM%20%2Brace%3AWhite&collection_id=2000219";
$url =~ s/ /+/g;
$mech->get($url);
```

Try that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Someone is not working though.  I get the error: "Global symbol "$url" requires explicit package name."

Comment: :D You have to assign your url to `$url` variable. I'll update the reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the error

```
Global symbol "$url" requires explicit package name.
```

this means that you forgot to declare `$url` with :

```
my $url;
```

---

Your *use* part seems freaky, I'm pretty sure that you don't need all of those modules @ the same time. If you use `WWW::Mechanize`, no need `LWP::UserAgent` and `CGI` I guess...